# Not possible to mount Windows 11 NTFS partition for read & write even with fast startup disabled

Tags: debian, mount, windows-11

I have disabled fast startup in the Windows control panel.

This always did the trick and it was possible to mount the partition (read & write) under linux. I have done this a lot of times for Windows 10.

But for Windows 11 it doesn't work.

I am booting debian 11.4 from an USB flash storage and I run:

```
mkdir moh
sudo mount /dev/nvme0n1p3 moh
```

But I get:

> Windows is hibernated, refused to mount.
> Falling back to read-only mount because the NTFS partition is in an
> unsafe state. Please resume and shutdown Windows fully (no hibernation
> or fast restarting.)
> Could not mount read-write, trying read-only

Any ideas?

Comment: Make sure Fast Startup is actually disabled and shutdown instead of rebooting to boot something else.

Comment: The diagnostic message is clear: "Windows is hibernated," leaving the disk marked "dirty". You can mount the disk **read-only** safely, or **force** mount it writable with the chance it will make Windows unbootable afterwards.

Comment: I have disabled fast startup and I also shutdown instead of rebooting.

Answer (score 3):

Windows hibernates when shutting down.  Restart actually does the opposite.

This is counterintuitive for me but Microsoft had their reasons I am sure.

First, see if the following command reproduces the problem: `Shutdown /s /t 0`.  This shutdown command shouldn't use the hibernation feature.

You might also try disabling the hibernation option altogether and see if it persists.. `powercfg -h off`.

Comment: `shutdown /s /t 0` was enough in my case.

Answer (score 0):

Considering you are in Ubuntu now...

1. unmount the partition if mounted already
2. Ctrl+Alt+T or launch terminal
3. Type:
   sudo ntfsfix /dev/partname

e.g. $ sudo ntfsfix /dev/nvme0n1p5

*Note: Worked in Win11 and Ubuntu 22.04 Dual Boot situation*